# Stop LINQ Query if Default Value is Returned at Any Point

Tags: c#, linq, default-value, syntactic-sugar, short-circuiting

Is there syntactic sugar or a method to "short-circuit" a LINQ statement within the same line when written in fluent syntax? For example if `null` is returned by a `FirstOrDefault` call, is it possible to return null otherwise continue with the rest of the method chain?

```
List<string> testList = new List<string>() { "some", "strings" };
var reversed = testList.FirstOrDefault(x => x == "hello").Reverse();
```

The `FirstOrDefault` call will return null so the statement will throw an `ArgumentNullException` on the `Reverse` call. Is there a way of stopping before the `Reverse` call since the default value was returned at that point?

(I know that the query can be broken into another line and `default(T)` can be checked before `Reverse` or, for simple cases, the conditional operator (`?:`) can be used but I'm curious if I'm missing a particular feature for longer/more complex chains)

**Edit - To clarify this is just an example to show the idea, it's not part of any actual code. I'd like to avoid exceptions being thrown as it would be more performant to just split the line and do a check.**

Comment: This doesn't make sense - `FirstOrDefault()` will only return a single element, so `Reverse()` doesn't make sense here...  What are you trying to do?

Comment: That was just an, admittedly contrived, example. I'm not actually doing that, or anything in particular, but it was just a scenario where null should be returned instead of continuing down the method chain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In cases where you want to resolve the set to a single item and manipulate that item, but still gracefully handle situations where that item may not be found in the set, you can can delay the `FirstOrDefault` until the very end, like this:

```
var reversed = testList
    .Where(x => x == "hello")
    .Select(x => x.Reverse())
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Or equivalently

```
var reversed = testList
    .Where(x => x == "hello")
    .Select(Enumerable.Reverse)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

This will return `null` if no items are in the list that satisfy the condition specified in the `Where` method. The performance difference here will be at most negligible. It won't require looping through the `testList` any more than the original code, since once the first element is found, the result is immediately returned.

Comment: I think the OP just gives some example to demonstrate the problem, I guess he may want to give another example because this one can be solved (worked around) by this.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Because we want to reverse the string, not the enumerable

Comment: Thanks, I've clarified my question. King King is right in that this is just an example which is easily solved but I'm not interested in the actual solution to that particular problem. I'm wondering if there's a language feature where, at any arbitrary point, a default value can be detected midway and the rest of the LINQ query stopped.

Comment: @keyboardP And this solution does that. If no item is found, the `Reverse` (or whatever you have after the `.FirstOrDefault`) is not performed.

Comment: Actually, that's exactly what `FirstOrDefault` does.  That's why it's much more performant than `SingleOrDefault`.

Comment: @pswg - Thanks, I think I was just overcomplicating things. I'm trying to remember a post I came across where this *may* not have worked. I'll accept your answer if I can't find that post/think of a better example but I guess the simplest ways are often the best :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just use First instead of FirstOrDefault; it will throw an exception earlier.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this isn't really what I'm looking for as the idea to avoid an exception. If an exception was to be handled, it could've been done at the Reverse call or, preferably from a performance point of view, to just split the query into multiple lines. I should've clarified that in my question.

Comment: Then the answer is unfortunately no. You seem to be asking about performance and from a performance perspective, the thrown exception is actually optimal.  If you know that's really the only reason for error in that block, just leave the catch entirely blank, don't even define the type of Exception and let it eat the error.

Comment: To clarify: splitting the query and doing if/then checks for nulls is much less optimal than just eating an exception.

Comment: @wilso132: I disagree. If he expects it more often to be not found then found or a reasonably high rate of "no results", exception can be a performance impact. 

Also, Linq usually do not gets executed until it's being enumerated (i.e. foreach loop) or converted to something (`.ToArray()` or `.ToList()`)

Comment: @Tseng I understand your argument, but I don't think it's correct.  Your suggestion to check for .Any() (issuing a query) and then perform another function (which would have to issue another query at some point) is much more intensive than handling and not even using the referenced exception.  You have a valid point if he's expecting a *lot* of exceptions, but I'd think it would have to be over 50% of the cases.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're after a C# version of the maybe monad.

```
public static class MaybeMonadExtensions
{
    public static TResult GetIfNotNull<TInput, TResult>(this TInput o, Func<TInput, TResult> evaluator)
        where TResult : class
        where TInput : class
    {
        return o == null ? null : evaluator(o);
    }
}
```

Using this, you can write

```
var reversed = testList.FirstOrDefault(x => x == "hello").GetIfNotNull(s => s.Reverse());
```

and that will output null if your list does not contain the word "hello".